# How to correctly apply a Substring-Filter to an Json array in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

im trying to filter a json data array that looks like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        "key": "FirstGroup",
        "color": "#1f77b4",
        "values": [
            {
                "label": "PWY-6089",
                "value": 0.0
            },
            {
                "label": "TOLSULFDEG-PWY",
                "value": 0.0
            },
           
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "SecondGroup",
        "color": "#78bf00",
        "values": [
            
            {
                "label": "PWY-4101",
                "value": 0.3
            },
            {
                "label": "PWY0-1356",
                "value": 0.5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "ThirdGroup",
        "color": "#d62728",
        "values": [
            {
                "label": "PWY-4101",
                "value": 1.0
            },
            {
                "label": "PWY0-1356",
                "value": 1.0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I want filteredData to be a subset of stackedChartData where the filterString is a substring of "label". This is my approach:

```
function startsWith(str, word) {
  return str.lastIndexOf(word, 0) === 0;
}
function filterData() {
  input = document.getElementById('filterInput');
  filterString = input.value;
  
  
  var filteredData = stackedChartData.filter(function (entry) {
        entry.values.forEach(element => {
        
         return startsWith(element.label,filterString);
            
        }); 
  });

 console.log(filteredData,"filteredData");
  
}
```

Since the String.startsWith() was not working properly I used the startsWith() in the code.
The filterString is what it should be and element.label refers to the correct property of my json file e.g. PWY-6089. Yet FilteredData remains empty.
I dont understand what im doing wrong here and would appreciate some help,
regards.

Comment: @ Hom, if the answer helped you kindly accept and vote, so it will be helpful for others in future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

For loop just iterates, doesn't returns anything

**Solution**

To get the filtered data, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in array methods

**Description** (below snippet example)

1. filter - out of 3 objects, i need to get 2
2. find - immediately returns when the startsWith condition is satisfied

see the below snippet code

```js
let data = [{
    "key": "FirstGroup",
    "color": "#1f77b4",
    "values": [{
        "label": "PWY-6089",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "label": "TOLSULFDEG-PWY",
        "value": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "SecondGroup",
    "color": "#78bf00",
    "values": [{
        "label": "PWY-4101",
        "value": 0.3
      },
      {
        "label": "PWY0-1356",
        "value": 0.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "ThirdGroup",
    "color": "#d62728",
    "values": [{
        "label": "PWY-4101",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "PWY0-1356",
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]

let filteredData = data.filter(datumn =>
  datumn.values.find(valueDatumn =>
    valueDatumn.label.startsWith('PWY-41') // for example, here you can pass the string from the user
  )
)

console.log(filteredData)
```